# Gompertz growth model problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

The growth of tumor cells is characterized with Gompertz model.

$N'=-aNln(bN),$

where  N(t) is proportional to the number of cells in the tumor, while a and b denote positive parameters.
Question:Which biological interpretation would you give to a and b? What do you think makes a Gompertz model better than a logistic growth?
Any kind of hint is appreciated.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: Gompertz  model is an asymmetric population growth model. Whereas many models are symmetric about their inflection point, the Gompertz model has different rates of exponent growth at the start and a decay toward the end. Whether its better really depend son how well it fits. For example, such models seem to fit the first wave of covid better than logistic models, according to some researchers.

Answer (score 4):

The parameter $a$ scales the time. The parameter $b$ reflects the *carrying capacity* $K$ through the identity $$K=1/b.$$ Recall that $K$ is the limit of $N(t)$ when $t\to\infty$ for every initial population, and that $K$ is also a threshold such that $N'(t)\gt0$ if $N(t)\lt K$ and $N'(t)\lt0$ if $N(t)\gt K$.

> What do you think makes a Gompertz model better than a logistic growth?

Are Gompertz models "better than" logistic ones?

Some differences concern the regimes where $N$ is very small or very large.

When $N$ is very small, the logistic growth $N'=aN(1-N/K)$ reduces to $N'\approx aN$ while Gompertz reads $N'\approx-aN\log N$ hence Gompertz populations grow more quickly than logistic ones, at very low initial populations. 
On the contrary, when $N$ is large, the logistic growth reduces to $N'\approx-(a/K)N^2$ while Gompertz reads $N'\approx-aN\log N$ hence Gompertz populations decrease less quickly than logistic ones, at high initial populations.